# When should you worry about tomato plants when they droop after transplant?

Tags: tomatoes

I've heard/seen tomato plants droop for a little while after planting them in bigger pots. When should you worry about your tomato plants after this happens?

[image]

Comment: More soaking when first transplanted.  Have you had any low temps lately below 40 degrees F?!  Cut off some of those leaves so the plant isn't laboring to resurrect dying leaves.  Adds more aeration/ventilation as well.  SOAK the roots firstest.

Comment: the photo was a reference. yes, when you transplant them from a cup.

Comment: So this is a theoretical question?

Comment: an actual wondering with a picture of plant wilt with the tomato plants I just put in

Comment: @Stephie someone can always edit for a better photo.

Comment: How should *we* be able to edit in photos of *your* plant?

Comment: Put another example of a transplant wilt tomato plant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait 10-14 days. If you see new growth, it's fine. In the meantime **make sure to water consistently every other day** r when they look droopy, sometimes you might have to water twice a day (I know I did). When you water, fill the pot with water until water comes out the drainage hole. But this assumes your temps have highs of 80F or so.

Generally when the temps hit 80F on any day, I water them really well. When high temps start reaching 88 I often have water the twice a day. If they look droopy, they are telling me they are thirsty, and I water them.

Comment: watering it every other day would drown the plant as it's the 2+ hours to drain type of soil in the pot I'm using as a little bit of grass plugs the hole.